# 1D Bayesian Inference clarification

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I'd like some help making sure I understand a 1D Bayesian inference problem. Stats.stackexchange wasn't helpful.

Say I have a data vector which is an array of the number of flu cases reported weekly in California for the past 10 years.

I want to compare two models which describe this data, via the odds ratio: $$\mathcal{O}_{ij} = \frac{P(M_i|D,I)}{P(M_j|D,I)} = \frac{P(M_i|I)\,\mathcal{L}(M_i)}{P(M_j|I)\,\mathcal{L}(M_j)}$$ where $$\mathcal{L}(M) = \int d\theta P(\theta|M_i)\mathcal{L}(\theta|D,M).$$

$M$ is model, $D$ is data, I'm not sure what $I$ represents.

I've developed two models, each of which are 1D vectors, one of which has parameters.

I'm new to Bayesian statistics. My confusion here is: what are $\mathcal{L}(\theta|D,M)$, $P(M|I)$, and $P(D|I)$ in relation to the dataset and the two models? I Think $P(D|I)$ is just the data. $P(M|I)$ is the prior but I don't know what that relates too, unless that's the model, in which case I don't know what the likelihood function $\mathcal{L}$ is.

Could someone help clarify this for me?

Comment: It's really impossible to answer if you don't give more info about your problem. Where do the symbols come from? If we don't get more information about $I$, $M$, and the other symbols we cannot hope to help you.

Comment: @RiccardoSvenRisuleo $M_i$ is a model, $D$ is observed data, and $I$ is prior information. Also $\mathcal{L}(M) = P(D|M)$.

Comment: @RiccardoSvenRisuleo I guess another thing to ask is how do I find the posterior of one model? I have a 1D vector representing the true data, and a 1D vector representing a model with no parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that $M_i$ and $M_j$ are two different models, $D$ is the observed data, $I$ is prior information, and $\theta$ is a parameter.

To formulate each model, we have available prior information that tells us how probable that model is **before observing the data**:
$$ p(M_i|I),\qquad p(M_j|I).$$

Each model represents a way of specifying the **prior distribution** of the unknown parameter:
$$p(\theta|M_i), \qquad p(\theta|M_j).$$

In addition, given the parameter, we can specify the **distribution of the data** (sometimes referred to as the *likelihood* of the parameter):
$$\mathcal L (\theta) = p(D|\theta).$$

The objective is to compare the odds ratio of the two models, to try and gauge which of them is more probable given the observed data $D$. To this end, we need to compute
$$\mathcal O_{ij} = \frac{p(M_i|D,I)}{p(M_j|D,I)};$$
If $\mathcal O_{ij} > 1$, the data and the information support $M_i$ more than $M_j$ (the converse is true if $\mathcal O_{ij} < 1$).

The problem is now that we do not have the posterior distribution of the models given the data. In theory, this could be computed using Bayes' theorem,
$$p(M_i | D,I) = \frac{p(M_i, D, I)}{P(D,I)} = \frac{P(D|M_i) p(M_i|I)}{p(D,I)},$$
but the normalization constant $p(D,I)$ is usually impossible to evaluate. However, this factor is common both in $p(M_i|D,I)$ and $p(M_j|D,I)$, so when we compute the odds ratio we can disregard it!
$$\mathcal O_{ij} = \frac{p(D|M_i)p(M_i|I)}{p(D|M_j)p(M_j|I)}.$$

Now we just need to compute $p(D|M_i)$; this is sometimes called *model evidence*, and we can find it using the sum-rule of probability theory

$$ p(D|M_i) = \int p(D,\theta |M_i) \mathrm d \theta = \int p(D|\theta)p(\theta|M_i) \mathrm d \theta = \int \mathcal L(\theta) p(\theta|M_i) \mathrm d \theta. $$

Comment: Thanks for this reply, it's helpful but not addressing my question. I have all these equations already. I can't find a good example to help me actually apply them. I'm working in Python. I have a 1D vector of the actual data $D$. I have a 1D vector for model $M_1$ with no parameters, and a 1D vector for model $M_2$ with four parameters. Both models are normalized about 1. How do I actually apply the above equations using these 1D vectors? What do I use as my priors?

Comment: I think you need to step backa bit and understand the basics of Bayesian inference. When we talk about models, we talk about probability distributions. All these $p(\cdot)$ are probability densities/mass functions. What do you mean when you say that $M_1$ is a vector?

Comment: By vector I mean 1D array of values. So $M_2$ might be the sum of two sine waves. If it were perfect, it would be the same as $D$ if $D$ were normalized. Maybe that's wrong? See, I've been given equations and the names of terms, but no good examples tying it into actual problems. What I have is a 52 length array of actual values $D$, and models $M_i$, also 52 length arrays which I've created. Edit: Also I appreciate you taking the time on this.